# Does this user really have so bad contributions?

Tags: discussion

I see nothing wrong with [this user](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/24257/pacerier#qpage_3-qsort_votes) which was suspended for low-quality contributions. Most of his questions are upvoted and only one answer has five downvotes.

Does anybody care to explain reason for his suspension?

Comment: Wow. This guy seems like a real parasite on programmers.se. <sarcasm />

Comment: Really worth considering, in these cases, that you're not seeing the whole picture. As Anna notes, mods won't discuss this without good cause, but if you're *really* curious, I recommend some creative googling...

Comment: Naturally, if content is bad enough to warrant suspension, don't you think they would *delete* it?

Comment: Consider: 22 questions + 4 answers = 1 reputation. Considering the upvotes on some of those questions, you're obviously not seeing something.

Comment: @SnOrfus When a user is suspended, their reputation is locked to 1. It gets reset to the actual value when they are unsuspended.

Comment: @MarkTrapp: Ah, that makes sense. I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Suspensions are a private matter between moderators and a user. We [do not discuss](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23385/avoid-the-streisand-effect-be-clear-about-the-reason-when-suspending-an-account/23548#23548) suspension reasons unless the issue is brought up by the person who got suspended.

Quoting from Jeff Atwood:

> I believe it is the reponsibility and right of the user who was placed in timed suspension to have the freedom to discuss (or *not* discuss) what happened to them.
>
> It is a basic matter of respecting other users' privacy.

Comment: it's ok to mention in this case there are 25 deleted questions and 5 deleted answers they can't see...

Comment: @JeffAtwood Good to know for next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Consider that what you are seeing is probably the situation after some of the posts have been deleted; in such case, you don't see the down-voted posts, and all you see are only up-voted posts that would make you think the user had good contributions. Also, eventual offending comments have been probably deleted, and you would not be able to see them.